# Почему не происходит подключение к MySql с помощью JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, mysql-workbench

День добрый. Я пытаюсь через Intelij Idea подключиться к бд MySql, но выдает только огромную тучу красного текста на консоль. Поиски в инете ничего не дали. Изюминка в том, что у меня 32-битная винда, а стандартный сервер mysql поддерживает только 64-битную ОС, но я вроде как скачал с офф сайта модифицированную версию на 32-бит. Может это как-то повлияло. Еще версия сервера 5.1.45, а MySql Workbench - 6.1.7

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] arg){
    final String db_url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1?useSSL=false";
    final String db_user="root";
    final String db_password="1234";
    final String db_driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    try{
        Class.forName(db_driver);
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, db_user, db_password)){
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        st.execute("select * from a");
        ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
        }
        System.out.println("Prepared statement");
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from a where a.key = ?");
        ps.setInt(1, 1);
        rs = ps.getResultSet();
        ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){

        }
    } catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

На подключении в последнем try выдает исключение:

```
    java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:108)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:87)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:71)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:79)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:862)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:444)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:230)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:226)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at Module_3.Labs.Labs_3.Main.main(Main.java:16)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.UnableToConnectException: CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:59)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:83)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:220)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1411)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:165)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:982)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:852)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Во-первых, текст кода вставляется прямо в вопрос не скриншотами, так же как и текст ошибки. Во-вторых, попробуйте добавить в конце url это: `?useSSL=false`. Не уверен, что поможет, но попытаться стоит.

Comment: сори, я просто впервые тут пишу. Совет, к сожалению, не помог, ничего не изменилось

Comment: Что это за отрывки кода? Как мы должны понять по вашим оторванным кускам, представьте мы вам куски вырвем, там не-допишем, тут не-допишем и что в итоге, все равно работать не будет. Нормально?

Comment: Полностью согласен, спасибо за совет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На вашем сервере установлен способ аутентификации, который вы не соблюдаете.

Почитайте [документацию](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/non-client-plugin-auth-clients.html)

Если не хотите заморачиваться возьмите старую версию драйвера, которая поддерживает текстовую авторизацию - вам нужен пакет

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```